# svn errors when build JEEAgent source code

Tags: eclipse, svn

I checked out JEEAgent source code and built it in eclipse followed the steps described in https://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam-dev/2014-March/001496.html

But I got an error:

```
enter code here

[INFO] --- maven-svn-revision-number-plugin:1.6:revision (default) @ jee-agents ---
[INFO] inspecting E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent\openam-agents\jee-agents
[ERROR] 
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: The path 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent\openam-agents\jee-agents' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent'.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:143)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.checkWCNG(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:145)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:190)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:366)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:274)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:267)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:317)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:476)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:441)
    at oe.maven.plugins.revision.RevisionMojo.getEntryProperties(RevisionMojo.java:152)
    at oe.maven.plugins.revision.RevisionMojo.execute(RevisionMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents ....................... FAILURE [57.704s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents AgentSDK .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents AgentApp .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat v6 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp Web Servlets  SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp Tomcat ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Distribution .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Distribution Tomcat v6  SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 58.798s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 07 13:44:09 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin:maven-svn-revision-number-plugin:1.6:revision (default) on project jee-agents: svn: The path 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent\openam-agents' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
[ERROR] working copy rooted at 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent'.
[ERROR] Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I met svn-plugin errors many times. It's quite annoying.

Preferences-Team-Svn-Svn Connector shows the version of my SVN connector: SVNKit 1.7.13 r10273_v20140502_1419(SVN 1.7.11 compatible, all platforms)

How Can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you need to upgrade your Subversion client, if that's possible - this is taken from the error message: `"The path 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent\openam-agents\jee-agents' appears to be part of Subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater
working copy rooted at 'E:\eclipse_worksapce\workspace\JEEAgent'.
Please upgrade your Subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy."`

Comment: I installed a new svn from Subclipse 1.8.x Update Site - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x   
But problem remains.The version of Subversion Client Adapter is 1.10.2

Comment: Did you reboot after updating? That should have updated the SVNKit to 1.7 according to the release notes, though if you're getting the same error it sounds like something isn't registering it as updated

Comment: I found the reason: the pom.xml configured svn as 1.6. It works after I delete svn plugin sentence.